# Why the following code can't modify the string in array of pointers?

Tags: c

I am trying to modify string "hello" to "Hello" but it's not working,neither it gives any error .Can someone please explain why it's not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *arr[] = {"hello" , "world"};
    char **p = arr;
    printf("%s\n",arr[0]);
    *(*(p+0)+1) = 'H';
    printf("%s\n",arr[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is writing on read only memory will produce segmentation-faul

Answer (score 6):

string literals are of type `char[]` and are stored in read only memory.  You cannot alter them.

If you want to alter them you need to create a char array.  What you have a is an array of pointers.

You can do this:

```
char foo[] = "Hello";
foo[0] = 'G';
printf("%s", foo);
```

Comment: String literals are of type `const char[len + 1]`, where `len` is the length of the string.

Comment: String literals are not const in C.

Comment: They're type `char []`, not `const` - but if a program modifies the literal, it's UB.

Comment: It's not universally true that string literals are stored in read-only memory; that depends on the architecture.  That's why the behavior is left *undefined*.

Answer (score 3):

Because you can't modify string literals (despite them being of an array type of non-const `char`). Your program invokes undefined behavior as-is.

Comment: no, string literals in C unfortunately are `char[]`. In C++ they are `char const[]`.

Comment: @JensGustedt I've been told several times that they're `const char[]` and also that they're `char []`. Both in the context of C. If I recall correctly, the reasoning for `char []` was that it's a backward-compatibility feature with K&R C and that it's true in C89. I don't know whether this has changed in C99, could you please cite the standard? I hate that every time I post an answer about this issue, somebody from the opposite group comes here and talks me off.

Comment: @H2CO3: 6.4.5.5 - "For character string literals, the array elements have type `char`"; + .6: "If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undeﬁned." (I just happened to be checking this recently)

Comment: C11 still says: *For character string literals, the array elements have
type char, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character
sequence.* and then *If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
undefined.* So yes they are `char[]` and no, you don't have the right to modify them.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *arr[] = {"hello" , "world"};
```

arr is array of pointers to char, so you cannot modify the string literals, the pointers are pointing to.

```
char arr[][6] = {"hello" , "world"};
```

arr is 2 dimensional array of chars - or array of two strings. You can modify them, but you need to specify the length of the second dimension of the array. It needs to be big enough to hold the longest strings.